# clientWidth detection is off by 15px, probably due to the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar that changes into a button with a slidetoggle function after a certain breakpoint and I've got this bit of jquery that handles it. In that mobile layout, it also makes the toggled navigation slide back up after an item was clicked.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        /* prepend menu icon */
        $('#nav-wrap').prepend('<div id="menu-icon">Menu</div>');

        /* toggle nav */
        $("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
            $(".nav").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
        });

        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 860) {
                $(".navitem").on("click", function(){
                $(".nav").slideToggle("slow");
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
            });             
        } });
```

The problem is, that my `.nav` hides after being clicked all the way up to width of 876. I suspect that this is due to the scrollbar, but I have no clue how to fix it. The site has a single-page layout so it's kind of important that the navbar stays there.
Any ideas?

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/0bbjn46g/ although it doesn't replicate the problem. What happens in chrome (and all webkit browsers I assume) is that `.nav` disappears after clicking on one of the items while width is 861-876.

Comment: Nope. Maybe if you gave me more to work with such as replicating this in jsfiddle, then I'd have some ideas stirring in my head but you don't... so sadly, I've got nothing for you.

Comment: added jsfiddle for a bit of context, but I wasn't able to replicate the problem

Comment: The width you get from JS and css media query is different due to the scrollbar. You need to sync both by checking an element. For example, set a div to display none in css for say <768 and in JS check for that element display property to make sure you are in the right width. I am only using display property for example, there are many options you can use with this methods. the width in css is the width of the page without scrollbar

Comment: If the fiddle doesn't replicate the problem, then the problem is somewhere else and the fiddle is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to take a stab at your problem throw my dart blindly but:

Your issue (from what I understand) is that your nav items disappear at a certain point. I'm assuming that they disappear when you shrink your window down to the mobile button menu and you click on it to hide the menu then resize the window, the navigation items are gone.

An easy solution to that is to force your nav menu to be `display: block !important;` when the browser size is bigger than the mobile: http://jsfiddle.net/0bbjn46g/6/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 /* prepend menu icon */
 $('#nav-wrap').prepend('<div id="menu-icon"><a><img id="navicon" src="img/navicon.svg"></a></div>');
 
 /* toggle nav */
 $("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
  $(".nav").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
 });

 if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 860) {
   $(".navitem").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").slideToggle("slow");
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });    
    }
});
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 861px) {
 #menu-icon {
  display: none;
 }
    .nav {
        display: inline;
    }
    
    .nav {
    display: block !important; /** note: when window is bigger than 861, force nav to show **/
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="menu-icon"><a>menu</a></div>
    <div class="nav" id="home">
     <ul>
      <li><a class="navitem" href="#">item 1</a></li>
         <li><a class="navitem" href="#">item 2</a></li>
         <li><a class="navitem" href="#">item 3</a></li>
         <li><a class="navitem" href="#">item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I feel completely silly for not thinking of putting up a display property for that media query. It worked, thank you!